# Fetch any service's properties from spring config server

Tags: spring, service, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Using spring cloud config properties can be defined for different services and different environments, e.g. using a native profile we could have the following tree in the server:

```
resources
  config
    service-a
      service-a-local.properties
      service-a-test.properties
    service-b
      service-b-local.properties
      service-b-test.properties
```

and have client services bootstrapped with configuration from the server, using one of the available options, such as `@Value` annotations etc. This however will only see the properties slice from the config server for the calling service (or whatever `spring.application.name` is used).

How can `service-a` access properties of `service-b` (or any other service) dynamically? The default property source locator uses a `"/{name}/{profile}"` path for fetch requests. I suppose one could restructure the entire configuration and put all services' properties in one file per environment, using some appropriate naming convention for the properties (e.g. using the service name as the prefix), and then explicitly prefix the calling-site property references with that prefix, but is there another/more elegant option, before using a discovery/mesh alternative?

Comment: Why do you want one service to access another service's properties?

Comment: One case would be a simple way of getting hold of another service's endpoint(s), by simply using that service's name as key (much like a discovery, but in a more rudimentary form).

Comment: Not via config-client, but you can use the http api.